# capturing a repeating pattern with regex

Tags: regex

I'm trying to match a pattern like this CODE-UH87H-98HSH-HB383-JWWB2U and I have the following regex pattern `CODE\-[A-Z0-9]+\-[A-Z0-9]+\-[A-Z0-9]+\-[A-Z0-9]+` but is there a better way of doing this? I tried `CODE(\-[A-Z0-9]+\-){4}` and it didn't work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried `CODE(\-[A-Z0-9]+\-){4}` and it didn't work

That does require two dashes in succession. In full, it would be `CODE\-[A-Z0-9]+\-\-[A-Z0-9]+\-\-[A-Z0-9]+\-\-[A-Z0-9]+\-`. What you want is

```
CODE(\-[A-Z0-9]+){4}
```

Answer (score 0):

You were almost there. `CODE(\-[A-Z0-9]+){4}` should work!

Answer (score 0):

When the pattern between the dashes may contain any character, the following regex is even shorter:

```
CODE(-[^-]+){4}
```

Of course you may have to add \ for escaping before the dash depending on what regex engine you will use.